# How to analyze the main memory and the cache access patterns?

Tags: memory-management, resources, hardware, kernel, virtualization

I am looking for a way how to analyze the main memory access times. Such method should give me a distribution of RAM and Cache accesses to analyze CPU stalls in time. I wonder if it's possible entirely in software (a kernel module?) or maybe a Virtual Machine may provide a feedback?

Answer (score 0):

The performance counters in modern x86_64 CPUs are perfect for determining what code is executing when there's events like cache misses, branch mispredictions, instruction/data TLB misses, prefetches, etc.

On linux, there's tools like `perf` and `oprofile`.  AMD and Intel both offer commercial tools (for linux and other platforms) to record and analyze these same performance counters.